# Why can't I answer a question in the review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, questions

I'm reviewing `First Posts` these days.

But sometimes I meet some first posted questions I want to answer.

But the point is I cannot answer there.

So I have to turn to leave a comment only.

What's the consideration about this case? Why can't we leave a post when reviewing questions?

Comment: What's preventing you from opening the Q in a different tab/window?

Comment: In my case, I would review it first (Upvote if it's useful and clear, no action needed if it's a legit question), and _then_ answer it. It __is__ the __review__ queue, after all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I remember you can always use a link to the original question to get it, just open the link in new tab or window.

[image]

But why can't you answer it in the review queue itself?

Because it is the "**review** queue" - not the "**answer** a question queue".

The goal of review queue is to analyze the quality of the post and improve(advise, close, delete...) it, so it is quite logical that review page does not support answering.

Also, not all posts in the review queue are questions, some of them are answers themselves.